# Troubleshooting custom VirtualPathProvider

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, iis-8, virtualpathprovider

I have just created a customized VirtualPathProvider for my ASP.NET web application. It basically maps all virtual files in "~/Storage" and subdirectories to a directory other than the solution's directory.

#### Code essentials

```
    private bool IsPathVirtual(string virtualPath)
    {
        String checkPath = VirtualPathUtility.ToAppRelative(virtualPath);
        return checkPath.StartsWith(VirtualRootPath, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    }

    public override bool DirectoryExists(string virtualDir)
    {
        return IsPathVirtual(virtualDir) ? ((FileSystemVirtualDirectory)GetDirectory(virtualDir)).Exists() : Previous.DirectoryExists(virtualDir);
    }

    public override bool FileExists(string virtualPath)
    {
        return IsPathVirtual(virtualPath) ? ((FileSystemVirtualFile)GetFile(virtualPath)).Exists() : Previous.FileExists(virtualPath);
    }
```

In my case `VirtualRootPath = "~/Storage"`, but that it configurable.

#### The problem

In IIS Express, when I debug via Visual Studio, the two public methods, required to resolve a virtual path, are not always called.

- Calling `http://localhost:7749/Storage` triggers breakpoints on both methods. A 404 error is returned and desired. This is a correct behaviour to me
- Calling `http://localhost:7749/Storage/ExistingFile.txt` doesn't trigger debug, and a different 404 error is returned. This is not correct

The difference between the two 404 errors is that when I call for the directory, it's ASP.NET responding (`Server error in application '/'`) but when I call for the file inside that directory, it's IIS 8.0 responding (`HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found`).

#### The question

Why, even if I correctly registered the `VirtualPathProvider` in my `HostingEnvironment`, doesn't IIS 8.0 let ASP.NET pipeline handle the HTTP request so it could be resolved correctly?

#### The workaround

After reading [VirtualPathProvider doesn't (quite) work in production on IIS 7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163058/virtualpathprovider-doesnt-quite-work-in-production-on-iis-7-5) I realized it could be a `Web.config` problem. Judging from the other question, it *looks like* that IIS handles certain file extensions independently, no matter if ASP.NET maps those to a virtual resource, a controller, or anything else. So, since I was trying to read an XML file (and perhaps not a JPEG), IIS didn't bother ASP.NET.

The workaround has been putting this line in `Web.config`'s `system.webServer.handlers` section:

```
<add name="AspNetStaticFileHandler-XML" path="*.xml" verb="*" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
```

But this workaround works only for XML files. How to make a permanent fix that works for all files under the storage directory?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the storage directory as part of the 'path' field in the config, as follows:

```
<add name="AspNetStaticFileHandler-Storage" path="Storage/*" verb="*" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
```

Comment: Although this code may be help to solve the problem,
providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.